# what does 1<<j signify?

Tags: loops, for-loop, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

These days,in the solution section of many algorithmic challenges,I see this particular phrase `1<<j`,which is sometimes given as an exit condition for a for-loop,
what is the significance of these `i<(1<<n)` and `1<<j`?

For example :

```
for(i=0;i<**(1<<n)**;i++)
       {
        sum=0;
          for(j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
            if(i&**(1<<j)**)
            {
             sum+=a[j];
            }
          }
          if(sum==m)
          {
             flag=1;
             break;
          }
       }
```

edit:by "what is `1<<j` ",I meant to what extent does the loop go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: This answers what a shift is and thats what you are asking essentially.

Comment: @codingwalebabu You should clarify your question ([edit] it), because as it currently is formulated, the answer to the linked question also answers this question. Maybe you need to explain better what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @tkausl , I asked what the significance of i<(1<<j) was

Answer (score 1):

In binary system, a power of 2 has a representation of `1` followed by zeros. For example:

**2<sup>5</sup>** = **32** (decimal) = **100000** (binary)

If you want to calculate a power of 2, shift a `1` several places left. The left-shift will fill the "new" places with zeros:

**1 << 5** (C/Java notation) = **100000** (binary) = **32** (decimal) = **2<sup>5</sup>**

So you can use left-shift as an easy way to calculate a power of 2.

---

You cannot calculate a power of e.g. 3 as easily. For example, the following C code will calculate a power of 3:

```
(int)(pow(3.0, 5.0) + 0.5)
```

It needs conversion to `int` (or another suitable type) if you want to use it in as a loop termination condition. This conversion looks ugly and it's possible to get it wrong (if you omit the `+ 0.5`).

So if you need a power of 2, and not any other number, it's easier to just use left-shift.